# Trying to update a property in my provider and pass value to controller

Tags: angular

I have a angular 2 / Ionic 3 project, where I'm trying to do the following:

I have a provider AuthenticationProvider, where I have a 'token' property.

From my loing.ts, I want to pass the login params to the provider, generate a token from the server, then store then update the 'token' property in the service so I can call it from other components.

I'm trying to return 'true' if success and 'false' if not successful.

However this doesn't work.

Here is my provider:

```
import {LoginResponse} from './../../types/interface';
import {AppSettings} from './../app-setting';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationProvider {
    public token: string = "";

    constructor(
        public http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getLogin(username: string, password: string) {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'APIKey': AppSettings.API_KEY
        });

        const body = new HttpParams()
            .set('grant_type', 'password')
            .set('metadata', 'device=android,appversion=2.0')
            .set('username', username)
            .set('password', password) ;

        const url: string = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/api/auth';
        this.http.post<LoginResponse>(url, body.toString(), { headers })
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.token = res.access_token;
                return true;
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            })
    }

}

export interface LoginResponse {
    "access_token": string;
    "expires_in": number;
    "expires": string;
}
```

and this is my login component:

```
import {AuthenticationProvider} from './../../providers/authentication/authentication';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

    loginId = '';
    password = '';
    pass:any;

    constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      public navParams: NavParams,
      private authService: AuthenticationProvider) {
    }

    login() {
      this.authService.getLogin(this.loginId, this.password)
        .subscribe(res =>{
          this.navCtrl.setRoot('nextPage');
        })
    }

}
```

If anyone can give me any advice on how to do this, that would be great.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you recieved token from this line?.  this.token = res.access_token;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iam Made changes of following,

Your Service File:-

```
getLogin(username: string, password: string) {      
    //All ways common service should be return type.(so here iam changed only one line)
    return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(url, body.toString(), { headers })            
}
```

Your Login File:-

Added one variable for Reference you to check valid or not.

```
 public isValid:boolean=false;
```

First way normally assign value success block and error block.

```
login() {
  this.authService.getLogin(this.loginId, this.password)
    .subscribe(res =>{
        this.authService.token = res.access_token;
        this.isValid=true; // here iam assign true value
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('nextPage');
    }), (err) => {
        this.isValid=false; // here iam assign false value
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Second way check token value is (null and undefined) then assigning value both.

```
login() {
  this.authService.getLogin(this.loginId, this.password)
    .subscribe(res =>{
        this.authService.token = res.access_token;
        if(this.authService.token!=null && this.authService.token!=undefined){
           this.isValid=true;  // here iam assign true value
        }
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('nextPage');
    }), (err) => {
        this.isValid=false;  // here iam assign false value
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

I hope this solve your problem perfectly.Lets try this once.

Regards,
Muthukumar.

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes in your service file & login componnt

```
getLogin(username: string, password: string) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'APIKey': AppSettings.API_KEY
    });

    const body = new HttpParams()
        .set('grant_type', 'password')
        .set('metadata', 'device=android,appversion=2.0')
        .set('username', username)
        .set('password', password) ;

    const url: string = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/api/auth';

    // Return from here
    return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(url, body.toString(), { headers });

}
```

login component

```
login() {
  this.authService.getLogin(this.loginId, this.password)
    .subscribe(res => {
        // set token in service from here
        this.authService.token  = res.access_token;
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('nextPage');
    }, (err) => {
           console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Agreed, best practice is to subscribe in the component and not in the service.

Answer (score 0):

I think `getLogin()` doesn't return observable so no need to subscribe from `login()` method in component.